# Rails 4, Bootstrap 3, form-inline input-group button in same row

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

still pretty new to all this, so thanks for any help here. I have read all the threads I could find but I think I understood the theory, just cant find the mistake in my individual setting:

I want to have a comment input field together with a post button in the same line.
My div is the following:

```
        <div class="input-group"> 
         <div class="form-inline">
            <%= form_for(@comment, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
             <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "Neuen Kommentar abgeben...", class:"form-control" %>
                 <span class='input-group-btn'>
                    <%= f.submit "Posten", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                </span>
                 <%= hidden_field_tag :parent_id, micropost.id %>
                 <%= hidden_field_tag :car_id, micropost.car_id %>
            <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have tried several other solutions that I have found, but it never puts them in the same row. I have already looked at my CSS and the divs on higher levels, but I cant seem to find it. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Best regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One way to accomplish inlining of form fields with the label is to use the bootstrap [add-on feature](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios)**

This is what the add-on inline form field looks like.

[image]

```
 <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="row">
            <%= simple_form_for(@comment, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <span class="input-group-addon input-group-xs" id="basic-addon1">
                <%= f.button :submit, "Posten", class: "btn btn-sm btn-default" %></span>
                <span class="input-group-addon input-group-xs" id="basic-addon1">
                    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "Neuen Kommentar abgeben...", class: "btn btn-sm btn-default" %></span>

                <span class="input-group-addon input-group-xs" id="basic-addon1">
                    <%= f.input :other_inline_field,  class: 'form-control input-group-xs nudge_down_6', required: false %></span>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group input-group-xs" style="display:block;">
                <small><%= link_to "inline link", somelink_here_path %> | </small>
                <small><%= link_to "inline link2"), other_link_path %> | </small>   
            </div>

        <% end %>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that did the trick (Mostly I think me having form-inline and input-group in the wrong order...

Comment: Maybe one thing missing in your example: How would you pass the "submit" that I am using?

Comment: So sorry, yes of course. I just added that to the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you keep things super simple when it comes to forms - trust me, when you are woking on multiple forms on a site and they may become more complex you don't want to be stuck with a lot of code. So keep it simple and consistent and plan well ahead how you structure them.

To answer your question - you can use [Rails Bootstrap form gem](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms) (that shall do for your purposes). It is easy to use and generates the HTML without having to code with overhead.

To answer specifically your question.

- keep the form_for on the outside.
- Here an example that may work for you (but again I would rather refer to the gem)

  ```
  = form_for @magazine, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
    .page-header
      %h3 #{t('magazines.index.header-1')}
    %p #{t('magazines.index.content-1')}
    .col-md-6.col-sm-12.col-xs-12
      %div.input-group
        %span.input-group-addon #{t('magazines.index.title')}
        = f.text_field :title, required: true, :class => "form-control"
   .col-md-6.col-sm-12.col-xs-12
      %div.input-group
        %span.input-group-addon #{t('magazines.index.summary')}
        = f.text_area :summary, :required => true, :rows => '4', :class => "form-control"
  ```

This is a simple haml snippet of one of our previous projects where we bothered to manually generate the form (as it was only for a single form). Hope this helps!

Replace the ".col-md-6.col-sm-12.col-xs-12" with the space you need. This is essentially how you place the fields next to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. I have seen the form gem pop up in some other posts, but did not have the time to look at it yet (kind of hoping I am done with forms for this project.. :D)

Comment: I know forms can be pretty annoying, so I learned to keep it super simple. Also with the addon inline form - bear in mind that if the addon is fairly long the field becomes super tiny on mobile devices (in portrait mode) ! I stay away from inline's as much as possible. But again, don't know the exact use-case ...