# Why is this appended bootstrap button misaligned?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, erb, bootstrap-sass

I'm trying to replicate [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons) example. However I'm getting the following result:

[image]

My code (index.html.erb):

```
<%= form_tag "/search", method: "post" do %>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <%= text_field_tag :txt, nil, placeholder: "Enter text", class: "form-control" %>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <%= submit_tag "Go", class: "btn btn-default" %>
                    </span>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Part of my Gemfile showing the relevant gems:

```
# Saas rails
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
# Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
# Autoprefixer - Automatically adds the proper vendor prefixes to your CSS code when it is compiled (optional)
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

Importing Bootstrap in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

Tried so far both in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Your code is right...do you have any links where you have this code, so that I can have a look..

Comment: Thanks. Actually this is pretty much it, the whole view of my index page. Could it be a browser issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if all of the following are needed but at least it works now!

```
<%= form_tag "/search", method: "post" do %>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
       <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
           <span class="input-group-btn input-group-lg">
               <%= text_field_tag :txt, nil, placeholder: "Enter text", class: "form-control" %>
           </span>
           <span class="input-group-btn input-group-lg">
               <%= submit_tag "Go", class: "btn btn-default" %>
           </span>
       </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125871/rails-4-bootstrap-3-form-inline-input-group-button-in-same-row) helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= form_tag "/search", method: "get" do %>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="input-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :txt, nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter text' %>
   <span class="input-group-btn">
     <%= button_tag( :class => "btn btn-default") do %>
        Go!
     <% end %> 
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Also try to make the method to :Post if this does not work....Let me know.

Comment: Thanks. Looks exactly the same though. Ah, yes of course it's post probably wrong copy paste.

Comment: @Michael: maybe you missed the %end% part... anyways did it work??

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work (exactly as above including the %end% part). I got it working though, check my answer. It surely doesn't look optimized but it's working.